# Criação de uma nova coluna usando o for

Tags: python, pandas

Olá pessoal estou usando essa base de dados 'https://cdn.tse.jus.br/estatistica/sead/odsele/votacao_partido_munzona/votacao_partido_munzona_2020.zip' para trabalhar. Gostaria de criar uma nova coluna no dataframe para classificar a ideologia.

```
df_vot = pd.read_csv('./Dados aula04/votacao_partido_munzona_2020_BRASIL.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'latin1')

centro = ['AVANTE', 'MDB', 'PROS', 'PSDB', 'SOLIDARIEDADE']


direita = ['DC', 'DEM', 'NOVO', 'PATRIOTA', 'PL', 'PMB', 'PMB', 'PODE', 'PP',
          'REPUBLICANOS', 'PRTB', 'PSC', 'PSD', 'PSL', 'PTB', 'PTC']

esquerda = ['PC do B', 'PDT', 'PMN', 'CIDADANIA', 'PSB', 'PSOL', 'PT', 'PV', 'REDE']


for v in df_vot['SG_PARTIDO']:
    if v in centro:
        df_vot['IDEOLOGIA'] == 'Centro'
    elif v in direita:
        df_vot['IDEOLOGIA'] == 'Direita'
    else:
        df_vot['IDEOLOGIA'] == 'Esquerda'
        
        
df_vot
```

Entretanto na saída que estou obtendo, apenas o primeiro if está 'funcionando'. A saída que estou tendo é igual a figura abaixo. Espero que possam me ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dados

```
df_vot = pd.read_csv('./Dados aula04/votacao_partido_munzona_2020_BRASIL.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'latin1')

centro = ['AVANTE', 'MDB', 'PROS', 'PSDB', 'SOLIDARIEDADE']


direita = ['DC', 'DEM', 'NOVO', 'PATRIOTA', 'PL', 'PMB', 'PMB', 'PODE', 'PP',
          'REPUBLICANOS', 'PRTB', 'PSC', 'PSD', 'PSL', 'PTB', 'PTC']

esquerda = ['PC do B', 'PDT', 'PMN', 'CIDADANIA', 'PSB', 'PSOL', 'PT', 'PV', 'REDE']
```

Sugiro você utilizar o loc juntamente com o isin

```
df_vot.loc[df_vot['SG_PARTIDO'].isin(centro), 'IDEOLOGIA'] = 'CENTRO'
df_vot.loc[df_vot['SG_PARTIDO'].isin(direita), 'IDEOLOGIA'] = 'DIREITA'
df_vot.loc[df_vot['SG_PARTIDO'].isin(esquerda),'IDEOLOGIA'] = 'ESQUERDA'
```

1. Verificamos se a lista está contida dentro do data frame
2. buscamos com o loc onde as ocorrências são verdadeira e inserimos o tipo de ideologia

Comment: Serviu perfeito! Muito obrigado

Comment: Bom dia @DiogoGouveiaJr! Que ótimo que serviu! Grande abraço!